# How to pass on variable to function in different script file

Tags: python-2.7, abaqus

Ich have one python file where I declare my variables and a second file containing more functions (in this example only one function). I can't seem to figure out how to pass on the variables from one.py to two.py.

one.py:

```
import two
a=1
b=2
c=3
dict={'ONE':a,'TWO':b,'THREE':c}
```

two.py:

```
def f():
    d=a+b+c
    return d
```

two.f() should return:

```
6
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

It's working fine in the command line in the mean time. But for some reason doesn't want to work when I run the script in Abaqus. It says:

```
count=two.f(my_dictionary)  
AttributeError:'Module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a module to make 'import two' work.
- Create a directory and put a blank **init**.py file there, two.py and one.py.

Your two.py should be:

```
def f(x):
    return x['ONE']+x['TWO']+x['Three']
```

Your one.py should be:

```
import two
a=1
b=2
c=3
my_dictionary={'ONE':a,'TWO':b,'THREE':c}
two.f(my_dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks so far, binayr. But I seem to be getting: TypeError: f() takes no arguments (1 given). Can you help me... I'm not a programmer, I'm very new to python

Comment: @wasntme0804 Copy the def f(x) : exactly how i have written here. This error is because it is not expecting a variable as you havn't defined one but passing it

Comment: I've copied the code exactly the way you have it. I have a folder, within it are included: one.py, two.py, init.py (init being an empty file). I execute the script one.py. As soon as i execute the script it gives me the error above. My next step would be: two.f(my_dictionary). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, figured it out. Didn't realize I had to give the directory the same name as the two.py file.... Might need your help again ;)

Comment: It's working fine in the command line. But for some reason doesn't want to work when I run the script in Abaqus. It says: count=two.f(my_dictionary) AttributeError:'Module' object has no attribute 'f'

Comment: Figured out the Abaqus Problem now too: There you need to import the class and not the module: from two import two

Comment: @wasntme0804 glad to know that you are learning python. It's an awesome language. Let me know if you need any help. My profile has all my contact details.